# How to convert AAC file in Swift?

Tags: swift, audio, codec

I have this Audio file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/996crway3omvx75/sample.m4a?dl=0

Which has the following specs:
[image]

I can't get it to work to play in HTML5 audio:

```
<audio controls src="sample.m4a" type="audio/mp4"></audio>
```

I know that using a different audio format I can get it to work, but I especially want this to work as this format is given to me by a content service provider. Now in Swift I can download the data. If I can't play it, does anyone know how I can convert this data, using Swift, into an audio format the audio tag does understand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26670299/312594

Comment: I am using Safari 9.0.1, but it doesn't work. It does work on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I can't open the file on my mac, althoug libav can play it. How are you creating it? `ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, iTunes AAC-LC` ought to work.

Comment: Did you try using the embedded `<source>` tag in the link I shared?  Might not work but probably worth a try...

Comment: We tried it also in source, but it doesn't work unfortunately. Also we did not compress it, the csp did. I am just trying to find a way to make it work in a WebKit environment. Does anyone know how to convert such a file perhaps?

Comment: Or does someone know what the Codec ID tells us. There is a difference between Codec 40 (playable) and Codec 67 (not playable).